# Does anyone have any advice for an English person going to Positivus festival in Salacgriva, Latvia?

Tags: festivals, estonia, tallinn, latvia, baltic-region

I'm finding it hard to find English-written reviews/advice of Salacgriva or the festival in general. In particular I'm wanting to find out if there's anything worth doing in the town or nearby, what the crime is like, what the nightlife is like (particularly midweek), what the prices are like, if the town takes Euros, if they speak good English (and can tolerate me speaking no Latvian), if any of the local bands playing this year are worth seeing, what the weather is usually like, etc.

Most of these questions also apply to Tallinn (Estonia) which I am visiting enroute, although there is slightly more English-written information for Tallinn (probably as it's the capital).

Links to informative websites are fine, but personal insight is preferred.

The festival website is here: http://www.positivusfestival.com/en

(I have been on obvious website such as Wikipedia, TripAdvisor and the local government websites.)

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question. Something that has one right answer. Open ended discussions and subjective questions are discouraged.

Comment: Also, try not to include too many questions in one. I'd at least remove the Tallinn part from here. Try asking more specific questions, something like "can I pay with euros in Salacgriva/Latvia" or "what the nightlife is like in Tallinn midweek". It's ok to ask lots of questions, as long as they are ontopic and answerable.